# Is there an approximate formula for this summation function?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, approximation-theory

Consider the function $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(nx)}{n^r},$$ where $r\in\mathbb{N}$. Is there any approximate formula (closed form possibly avoiding this type of summation) for this function? I want to avoid doing the summation over $n$.

Similarly, for higher dimension, has the summation $$\sum_{l\in\mathbb{Z}^m\setminus\{0\}} \frac{\cos(l\cdot x)}{\|l\|_2^{2r}},$$ $x\in\mathbb{R}^m$, $l = (l_1,l_2,l_3,\ldots,l_m)\in\mathbb{Z}^m$ a closed form?

Comment: Is the $\cos(nx)$ in the denominator or at the top? If it is the former, see the link below. If at the top, the series is not defined at many points, and divergent at 0, what type of convergences are you trying to use? https://math.stackexchange.com/a/322055/9176

Comment: @NickS : $cos(nx)$ is in numerator.

Comment: Then, your series is the Fourier series of some function, see the stackexchange link.

Comment: @NickS : Thank you. I have added a request for a higher dimension.

Comment: These are related to the Fourier expansion of the (periodic) Bernoulli polynomials and/or to a Lerch zeta function. Both should appear in their wikipedia articles.

Comment: $\ell x$ is the dot product?

Comment: @GerryMyerson : Yes, $lx$ is a dot product.

Comment: For the one-dimensional sum, once you have one (well, two) of them, you can get the ones for other $r$ by integration/differentiation.

Comment: @efs: Is there any work on defining multi-dimensional Bernoulli polynomials (definition as per desired in the question) and computing them? (or even atleast multi-dimensional Lerch zeta function). The multi-dimensional definition is desired, as shown in its Fourier series-type summation in the second equation of the question.